# InvalidCastException при преобразовании IQueryable в List

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite, entity-framework, linq2sql

Есть БД SQLite. В ней есть таблица Studios со следующей структурой:

```
CREATE TABLE Studios (
    id            INT     PRIMARY KEY
                          UNIQUE
                          DEFAULT (0) 
                          NOT NULL,
    name          STRING,
    filtered_name STRING,
    real          BOOLEAN NOT NULL
                          DEFAULT true,
    image         STRING
);
```

Заполняется она корректно и без ошибок из List.

Взаимодействие через linq2db. Классы-сущности созданы по шаблону, который шёл с библиотекой.

```
public partial class FiltersDB : LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection
{
    public ITable<Studio>    Studios    { get { return this.GetTable<Studio>(); } }

    public FiltersDB()
    {
        InitDataContext();
    }

    public FiltersDB(string configuration)
        : base(configuration)
    {
        InitDataContext();
    }

    partial void InitDataContext();
}

[Table("Studios")]
public partial class Studio
{
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull    ] public int    id            { get; set; } // int
    [Column,        Nullable] public string name          { get; set; } // string(max)
    [Column,        Nullable] public string filtered_name { get; set; } // string(max)
    [Column,     NotNull    ] public bool   real          { get; set; } // boolean
    [Column,        Nullable] public string image         { get; set; } // string(max)
}

public static partial class TableExtensions
{
    public static Studio Find(this ITable<Studio> table, int id)
    {
        return table.FirstOrDefault(t =>
            t.id == id);
    }
}
```

Получить значение таблицы пытаюсь следующим методом:

```
    public static List<ShikiApiLib.Studio> GetStudiosFromDB()
    {
        using (var db = new FiltersDB("Filters"))
        {
            var response = new List<ShikiApiLib.Studio>();
            var table = db.Studios.Select(x => x); //(!)для дебага
            var table1 = table.ToList(); //(!)для дебага
            foreach (var studio in db.Studios.Select(x => x).ToList())
            {
                response.Add(new ShikiApiLib.Studio()
                {
                    id = studio.id,
                    name = studio.name,
                    filtered_name = studio.filtered_name,
                    real = studio.real,
                    image = studio.image
                });
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
```

на строчке с table1 выскакивает ошибка `System.InvalidCastException: "Заданное приведение является недопустимым."`

Причём в table отображается следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:** 
Если удалить из таблицы все строки, у которых в столбце *image* стоит *null*, то ошибка не появляется =/

Но это **не** решение проблемы, так как эти строки мне нужны =/

**UPD2:** 
С этим столбцом мистика какая-то. Ибо замена null на пустую строку или текст вроде "no_image" перед занесением в таблицу БД не помогает. а удаление этих строк, снова избавляет от ошибки =/

Comment: `real` это тип в SQLite, возможно поэтому в селекте добавлен as

Comment: @Grundy у меня real это имя поля и оно bool =/

Comment: Ну так попробуй переименовать его. например в _isReal_ и посмотри, исправится ли ошибка

Comment: @Grundy изменил эту строчку так: `[Column(Name = "real"),     NotNull    ] public bool   isReal          { get; set; } // boolean` всё тоже самое =/

Comment: а в чем смысл изменений, если ты указываешь `Column(Name = "real")`?

Comment: @Grundy вы предлагами именно имя поля в БД поменять?

Comment: да, именно имя в бд.

Comment: @Grundy значение в table изменилось.. "as" исчезло - http://pastexen.com/i/ELVURjHf5c.png  Но вот ошибка осталась.. =/ видимо проблема не в этом или не только в этом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В чём была магия я так и не понял, но проблема решилась следующим образом:

Вместо того, чтобы использовать заранее заготовленную БД, я создавал БД и таблицы непосредственно в коде примерно следующим образом:

```
using (var db = new FiltersDB("Filters"))
{
    db.CreateTable<Studio>();
}
```

С моим классом сущностью получилась таблица примерно следующего вида:

```
CREATE TABLE Studio (
    id            INTEGER        PRIMARY KEY
                                 NOT NULL,
    name          NVARCHAR (255),
    filtered_name NVARCHAR (255),
    real          BIT            NOT NULL,
    image         NVARCHAR (255),
    )
);
```

С null в image также работает =/

Answer (score 1):

Строка `[t1].[real] as [real1]` тут ни при чем - это просто назначение псевдонима.

Настоящая проблема - в том, что в БД находятся данные, типы которых не соответствуют указанным. SQLite - нетипизированная СУБД, и типы колонок в ее таблицах - не более чем подсказка (ну и еще они задают порядок колонок).

Проверьте, не лежит ли в вашей базе в колонках id или real вместо числа или булева типа маскирующаяся под них строка.

Также возможно, что тип `id` на самом деле не int, а long. Проверьте этот вариант тоже. Кстати, в SQLite для первичного ключа использовать long предпочтительнее, это немного ускоряет доступ и уменьшает занимаемое место.

Еще один возможный вариант - в real на самом деле лежит число, а не булев тип. Попробуйте int или long.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59786/discussion-on-answer-by-pavel-mayorov-invalidcastexception---iq).